# Surjectivity and exactness on higher homotopy groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

If $X$ is a normal algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and $U$
an open set of $X$ then we have surjectivity on the fundamental groups
$ \pi_1(U)\rightarrow \pi_1(X)$.

If $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ is a morphism
(not necessarily a fibration) of smooth algebraic varieties
over $\mathbb{C}$, under some conditions on the general fiber $F$
of this morphism we can write an exact sequence:

$$ \pi_1(F)\rightarrow \pi_1(X)\rightarrow \pi_1(Y)\rightarrow 1 $$

1. There exists a generalization of this facts on higher homotopy?

I'm interested in the case when $f$ is a quotient for the action
of an algebraic group on $X$.

1. Is there any conditions such that $f$ is a fibration?

I've read somewhere that proper and separable should be a sufficient condition. is this true?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_group#Long_exact_sequence_of_a_fibration